# Open Graph Tags automatic

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

My website has lots of seperate articles and I need a way to automatically create the OG tags for each notice.

I have filled the OG tags, but it seems wrong while testing it on FB debugger.

**Code below:**

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name (Can be Static)"/> 
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/> 
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title;?>"/> 
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $content;?>" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://url.com/index.php?action=show&type=<?php echo $type;?>&id=<?php echo $id;?>"/> 
<meta property="og:image" content="something.php" /> 
<meta property="fb:admins" content="someid"/>
```

**Notice attributes:**

Title = `$title`
Content = `$content`
Notice type = `$type`
ID = `$ID`

It's all dynamic.

How to fix that??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you add that line too ?

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# http://ogp.me/ns/fb/[your name space]#">
```

Which kind of error do you get from the Linter ?

Comment: I could solve my issue.
The problem was a bad mysql call and so the content wasn't being shown.

Comment: It's needed to specify your OpenGraph App Namespace. And tells what "og:" type of parameters are.
It defines all the OpenGraph namespaces.

Comment: I haven't added that, and it's working. Also I haven't added since I don't know what to put on the "name space" space.

Comment: The namespace is defined in your Facebook App settings. Check http://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: Are you saying to me that in order to have OG Tags I need to do an FB APP?